# Add event listener to all objects except for a few selected?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

I'm trying to add event listener to all objects except for a few selected (the selected also have arbitrary child elements in arbitrary levels)?

I have asked this question before, but I didn't really got an answer to it. I have came close to solve it. Could you please help me with debugging it?

I'm adding an event listener to the body element called `bodylistener` and an event listener to the few selected elements called `selectedElementsMarkTrue`. The few selected elements that I don't want to execute some code, the listener `selectedElementsMarkTrue` performs prior to `bodylistener` with `setTimeout function`. `selectedElementsMarkTrue`set the variable `selectedElements` to `true` and `bodylistener`checks if `selectedElements` is `true` before execute some code. There is still something wrong with my code:

```
var selectedElements = false;
var bodylistener = function(){
    window.setTimeout(function(){//Setting timeout so that the other handler, selectedElementsMarkTrue, always performs first
        (function(){
            if(selectedElements == false){
                //Do some stuff
            }else{
                selectedElements = false;
            }
        });
    }, 10);//Could be 0, but te be sure I set 10
};
var selectedElementsMarkTrue = function(){
    selectedElements = true;
};
$('#dontAddEventListener1, #dontAddEventListener2').each(function(){
    this.addEventListener('click', selectedElementsMarkTrue, false);
});
document.body.addEventListener('click', bodylistener, false);
```

I can't get the `setTimeout` function to execute the underlying code?

Comment: I will flag my my other question, which is similar to this question after solving this question

Comment: Please vote this question up. If you think it is important to know.

Comment: you can stop event propagation for which you don't want to trigger parent's click event.

Comment: $('#dontAddEventListener1, #dontAddEventListener2').click( function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
  return false;
    });

Comment: @NarenSisodiya You should add that to your answer, it solved my issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you want behavior something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <script>
            window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
                document.body.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                    var el = e.target;
                    do {
                        if (el.hasAttribute && el.hasAttribute("data-nofire")) {
                            return;
                        }
                    } while (el = el.parentNode);
                    alert('do stuff');
                }, true);
            }, false);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><span>click me</span></p>
        <p data-nofire><span>click me</span></p>
        <p data-nofire>click me</p>
        <p>click me</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Or, you could do it something like Naren suggested:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <script>
            window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
                var nofire = document.getElementsByClassName("nofire");
                for (var i = 0; i < nofire.length; ++i) {
                    nofire[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                        e.stopPropagation();
                    }, true);
                }
                document.body.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                    alert('do stuff');
                }, false);
            }, false);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><span>click me</span></p>
        <p class="nofire"><span>click me</span></p>
        <p class="nofire">click me</p>
        <p>click me</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have never understood `capture`, I mean the third argument in `addEventListener` could you explain it to me?

Comment: I forgot that the elements-do.not-fire also have child elements

Comment: ok it worked. I didn't used window.addEventListener wrapper though. But how do I remove the event listener in the body element?

Comment: @Woho87, maybe <http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/event-capture-explained/> will help?

Answer (score 0):

prevent event propagation by handling elements click event

```
$('#dontAddEventListener1, #dontAddEventListener2').click( function(event){ event.preventDefault(); return false; });
```