# Using addEventListener and getElementsByClassName to pass an element id

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I'm defining a list of items from a JSON file and displaying that list on a web page. The intention is for users to click on any item in that list to display more information on that item (information that is held in the same JSON file).

All items of that list are members of the same class, and each has a unique id defined from the JSON file. The HTML looks something like this:

```
<ul>
   <li class="menu" id="bob">Robert Smith</li>
   <li class="menu" id="jane">Jane Doe</li>
   <li class="menu" id="sue">Susan Carter</li>
</ul>
```

I was planning to use something along the lines of

`var userSelection = document.getElementsByClassName('menu');`

in concert with

`userSelection.addEventListener('click', myFunctionToPrintDetails());`

but I am not sure how to pass the id from the event listener to the print function in order to determine which details to print.

I have a lot of experience with HTML/CSS but very little with JSON/AJAX, so possible I'm going about this completely bass-ackwards. If there is a more appropriate way to get this done I'm open to the feedback.

I tried both answers but neither worked. When I log userSelection.length to the console I get 0; when I log userSelection I get:

```
HTMLCollection(0)
> sue: li#sue.menu
length: 3
> jane: li#jane.menu
> bob: li#bob.menu
> 0: li#bob.menu
> 1: li#jane.menu
> 2: li#sue.menu
```

Comment: Add the listener to _each_ element in the `userSelection` collection. Add the listener using the function name, `myFunctionToPrintDetails`, not a call to the function. Inside the handler the element clicked is the `this` value, assuming you have not used a lambda expression (arrow function) for the handler.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[codepen demo](http://codepen.io/bubblesphere/pen/PWBQRo)

```
var userSelection = document.getElementsByClassName('menu');

for(var i = 0; i < userSelection.length; i++) {
  (function(index) {
    userSelection[index].addEventListener("click", function() {
       console.log("Clicked index: " + index);
     })
  })(i);
}
```

As pointed out by @torazaburo in the comments, you can use the following if the browsers you want to support are complying with ECMAScript 6 (ES6), the newest version of JavaScript.

```
var userSelection = document.getElementsByClassName('menu');

for(let i = 0; i < userSelection.length; i++) {
  userSelection[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("Clicked index: " + i);
  })
}
```

Comment: where is `index` defined? What is its value after the loop has finished?

Comment: It was a typo, fixed now.

Comment: There's still the "infamous javascript loop issue" - `i` is set to `userSelection.length` when the click occurs. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/5217142

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, you're right. I added an IIFE to fix the issue.

Comment: I tried both solutions to but wasn't getting anywhere. userSelection.length to the console I get 0, but when I print userSelection I get: HTMLCollection(0) > sue: li#sue.menu length: 3 > jane: li#jane.menu > bob: li#bob.menu > 0: li#bob.menu > 1: li#jane.menu > 2: li#sue.menu

Comment: Are you sure you called `var userSelection = document.getElementsByClassName('menu');` before calling `userSelection.length`? If so, compare your result with a [codepen implementation](http://codepen.io/bubblesphere/pen/PWBQRo) of my solution

Comment: All of this rigmarole with IIFE's in the loop is unnecessary with `let`.

Comment: In the second form you might as well use `const` for the `userSelection`: `const userSelection = document.getElementsByClassName('menu');` See this [explanation](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/var-let-and-const-whats-the-difference/) or ask google, if you don't know why.

Answer (score 7):

Here's how I would do it. I would first create an array using Object values.

```
const userSelection = Object.values(document.getElementsByClassName('menu'));
```

Then I would loop through them using a foreach.

```
userSelection.forEach(link => {
    link.addEventListener(('click', event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        // more code here
    });
});
```

Easy peasy!

Comment: Same approach using `Array.from`
`Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('menu')).forEach((elem) => {
 elem.addEventListener("click", (e) => {});
});`

Comment: ```addEventListener``` requires 2 params, but only the 2nd param is provided. The event to handle is missing and should be before the arrow function.

Answer (score 6):

You can get the id from the element that responded to the click event with `this.id`:

```js
var items = document.getElementsByClassName('menu');
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  items[i].addEventListener('click', printDetails);
}

function printDetails(e) {
  console.log("Clicked " + this.id);
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li class="menu" id="bob">Robert Smith</li>
   <li class="menu" id="jane">Jane Doe</li>
   <li class="menu" id="sue">Susan Carter</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I tried both solutions to but wasn't getting anywhere. userSelection.length to the console I get 0, but when I print userSelection I get: 

    HTMLCollection(0)
    > sue: li#sue.menu
    length: 3
    > jane: li#jane.menu
    > bob: li#bob.menu
    > 0: li#bob.menu
    > 1: li#jane.menu
    > 2: li#sue.menu

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul id = "menuList">
   <li class="menu" id="bob">Robert Smith</li>
   <li class="menu" id="jane">Jane Doe</li>
   <li class="menu" id="sue">Susan Carter</li>
</ul>


// JS - Event Bubbling
const menuList= document.getElementById("menuList");
menuList.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        console.log(e.target); // log clicked element 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shorter version I'm using all the time:

```
[...(document.getElementsByClassName('__MYCLASSNAME__'))].forEach(d => {
  d.addEventListener('click', MYFUNCTION__);
})
```