# Open a pop-up on a link using javascript

Tags: javascript

this must be simple to a lot of you guys, but I'm only starting learning javascript and tried to follow a lot of tutorials and none worked.

I'm building a site using Wordpress and can't add javascript natively on menu links, so I added a class to identify the link and add a function externally, my last attempt was the following code:

```
<a class="radioPlayerLink" href="#">Listen do the radio player</a>
```

And tried to add javascript with the following script:

```
        <script>
        var radioPlayer = document.getElementByClassName("radioPlayerLink");

        radioPlayer.addEventListener("click", abrirPlayer);

        function abrirPlayer(){
          window.open('https://portalrdx.com.br/player-rdx.html', 'aio_radio_player', 'width=720, height=355'); return false;");
        }
    </script>
```

I'm not interested in Wordpress solutions, but on to making javascript works, be as explicative as you can to show where I got wrong (probably all of it).

Thank you :)

Comment: Try: `radioPlayer[0].addEventListener("click", abrirPlayer);` instead. More info: [Using addEventListener and getElementsByClassName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42080365/using-addeventlistener-and-getelementsbyclassname-to-pass-an-element-id). Also, `getElementByClassName` has typo.

Comment: Also `document.getElementByClassName("radioPlayerLink");` is a typo. `document.getElementsByClassName("radioPlayerLink");` is correct. Better to use `document.querySelectorAll(".radioPlayerLink")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `");` after return false should not be there

```
function abrirPlayer() {
    window.open('https://portalrdx.com.br/player-rdx.html', 'aio_radio_player', 'width=720, height=355');
    return false;
}
```

it makes the javascript syntax incorrect.

And its `document.getElementsByClassName()` with an `s`. `getElementById()` doesn't have this `s` as it gets a single element. Then you have to get the first element of the array `[0]`.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("radioPlayerLink")[0].addEventListener("click", abrirPlayer);
```

Apart from that, I suppose you wanted to write 'Listen **to** the radio player' :)

Test it working [here](https://codepen.io/jeprubio/pen/oNXOmxG)

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

*getElementsByClassName()* returns an array of node elements, even if only one exists. Noticed the "s" in getElement**s**ByClassName ? :)

You have plenty of choices then:

```
// This will work only if you found an element by the class you searched for
if (radioPlayer.length === 0) return console.error('No <class> found!');
radioPlayer[0].addEventListener();
```

Comment: thank you for the tip, really useful :)

Answer (score 0):

check this solution on js fiddle:  [check here](https://jsfiddle.net/rss81/ndbL76mw/)

```js
var radioPlayer = document.getElementsByClassName("radioPlayerLink");

        radioPlayer[0].addEventListener("click", abrirPlayer);

        function abrirPlayer(){
          window.open('https://portalrdx.com.br/player-rdx.html', 'aio_radio_player', 'width=720, height=355'); 
          return false;
        }
```

```html
<a class="radioPlayerLink" href="#">Listen do the radio player</a>
```

Comment: Thank you very much  :)